# Craft CMS allows a zero sale when going direct to /checkout link

Tags: php, content-management-system

I have a client that has a craft CMS site selling apartments
and he has had a few sales coming in for a zero amount

and we wasn't sure how this is happening as all apartment have a min 250.00 deposit scheme

browsing the apartments is fine when you find one you go and book it with a deposit.

but we have found out if you don't look at any apartments and in an incognito window just go directly to domain/checkout

you are allowed to fil in a form and pay a zero amount. this is causing a problem as they are getting quite a few like this now.

is there a way anyone knows how to stop access to /checkout if the value is a zero rate

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the field type of rate is number. Set the Min value of the rate field is 1. so the form does not take the rate value is 0.